# Standalone GeoWebCache drop some parts of features in tiles

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, geowebcache, pbf

I have a local GeoServer with standalone GeoWebCache to serve vector tiles in PBF file format. The layer displays country borders in the world but the problem is in different tiles some parts of polygons missed and have not shown. You can see the difference between the two following images.

[image]
[image]

The geoserver logs these line but I cannot find any layer group named web:

```
2020-05-05 17:14:22,133 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-05-05 17:14:36,404 DEBUG [geoserver.wps] - Removing statuses matching [[[ NOT [ completionTime IS NULL ] ] AND [ completionTime Before 2020-05-05T17:09Z ]] AND [[ NOT [ lastUpdated IS NULL ] ] AND [ lastUpdated Before 2020-05-05T17:09Z ]]]
2020-05-05 17:15:15,606 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: filter=false'; against '/web/'
2020-05-05 17:15:15,606 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: filter=false with /web/
2020-05-05 17:15:15,609 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-05 17:15:15,609 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-05 17:15:15,609 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-05 17:15:15,609 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-05 17:15:15,610 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 142 locking in mode READ
2020-05-05 17:15:15,610 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 142 got the lock in mode READ
```

Comment: Please ask only One question per Question, as per the [Tour].

Comment: do png tiles work OK? if so it's a PBF problem, if not then it's a datastore issue, then we probably need to know more about your set up and where the data is stored. In either case we need to see if there are any error messages in the log file (both GeoServer and GWC)

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, the png format is ok so I've added the detail to the question.